# how to set image url in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, ckeditor

I'm using Codeigniter 2.2 , i have created admin Panel .
this is my file structure
localhost base_url is 
**localhos/project/3/**

url for my admin panel controllers were stored in

**base_url/admin-(application/controllers/admin)**

and my user controllers were stored in

**base_url/ - (application/controllers/)**

i have article options in admin panel and configured **CKEDITOR** file upload.
file upload directory is

**application/uploads**

everthing works fine till here.i got problems in setting image url for the uploaded images.

if i set the URL as "**../application/uploads/filename**", works on admin panel but not in User View.

if i use this "**application/uploads/filename**" it doesn't work in admin panel but work in User View. 
I have a other choice by setting the by **base_url()/uploads/filename** . If i use this i want to change each and every image tag in database if i change any folder. It will be a big Mess.

Comment: did you try by using application path `APPPATH` ?

Comment: @AshokMaharjan yeah i tried but `APPPATH` will return **application**

Answer (score 0):

It very simple just call file path like this

```
$file_path = APPPATH.'uploads/filename.jpg';
```